# Stanford Parser Installation Fails on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, jython, stanford-nlp

Edit:
Just let me know what is the "rake setup"?

This is my second day of trying to get the stanford parser on windows 7 to work with python. I stumbled upon this way to install it - using this python interface - http://projects.csail.mit.edu/spatial/Stanford_Parser.

In the installation instructions they require to use rake file setup, but when i using command prompt in windows 7 navigate to the 3rdParty/jpype directory and type in "rake setup" I get an error.

```
We developed a python interface to the Stanford Parser.  It uses JPype
to create a Java virtual machine and convert between python and Java.
Most of the code is about getting the Stanford Dependencies, but it's
easy to add API to call any method on the parser.

JPype is included; you can set compile it by running "rake setup" in
3rdParty/jpype.  The Stanford Parser can be downloaded and installed
by running "rake download; rake setup" in 3rdParty/stanford-parser".
Otherwise set the environment variable STANFORD_PARSER_HOME to the
location of the installed directory.  It loads the grammar file from
the unzipped version, because the load is a few seconds faster.  If
you haven't gunzipped the .ser file you will get an error.

To see how to use it, look at parser_test.py.
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message to me.

Comment: might help if you show the actual error message...

Comment: well the command prompt says: "rake" is not recongised. By the way what is the rake installation?

Comment: I still cannot post images here

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Rake isn't in your PATH.

## What is Rake?

Rake is a build automation tool written using Ruby. If you've ever used UNIX `make`, it's similar, except you write your build file in Ruby.

If you don't know what `make` is, just imagine a really fancy batch file that builds a program, except that it only rebuilds what's changed since the last build.

## How do I install Rake?

### Installing Ruby and RubyGems

#### Using RubyInstaller

Go to http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and download the Ruby 1.9.3 installer. Now run it. Proceed as any other installer until you reach the screen that lets you choose an installation directory. Here, select the box labeled `Add Ruby executables to your PATH`. Here's an image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [forwardhq.com](https://forwardhq.com/assets/screenshots/support/installing-ruby-windows/rubyinstaller-settings-bd11f3413e9426d4a90f2acc5faaaf32.png))</sub>

#### Using Chocolatey

Download and install Chocolatey by opening a command prompt and running the following long command:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
```

Once that's done, run the following command(you may need to restart the command prompt window):

```
cinst rubygems
```

Note that these may take a while to even show a sign of moving.

### Installing Rake

Once Ruby is installed, pop up a command prompt and run:

```
gem install rake
```

Voila! Now `rake` should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks i dd manage to install it without any errors but still there is error after i type rake setup = command failed with status 127

Comment: I am not sure are people form http://projects.csail.mit.edu/spatial/Stanford_Parser weird or something. If they do not want me to use their software then simply shouldn't put it on web. Not luring me to install theitr stupid software that cannot be installed and waste my and your time  as well.

Comment: @Brana: 127? That's a Linux exit code, not Windows. Are you in a Posix shell, such as MinGW or Cygwin?

Comment: It is related to unziping

Comment: @Brana: Can you post the full error message? Don't lose hope. Whenever you install developer stuff on Windows, it always takes 27 tries and 9 lives. Oh, the charms of MS...

Comment: Please check this one as it should be simpler - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888629/cannot-install-malt-parser-on-python-windows. There is no way for me to install this software as i even wasn't able to install this one and I followed the instructions and there are only 2-3 steps.'

Comment: What is wrong with those programmers so they cannot make any software that work properly and add proper installation instruction.

Comment: @Brana: Please don't insult people over that. Usually, as I said, most things are designed for POSIX-style systems. Now, first of all, CMD's set(if that's what you used) does NOT set variables globally; you need to go to System Settings for that.

Comment: If i were in their shoes i wouldn't feel offended. It takes many days to test and deuig a software and just few hours to document it.

Comment: @Brana: You set the environment variable in System Settings?

Comment: I didn't do it manually,only in the picture. It should be C:\Chocolatey\bin. But I gave up, as I tried to install Stanford Parser, Stanford CoreNLP and Malt - software which support dependency grammar and failed each time. I wasted really long time over that, and I still was able to somehow install Stanford and TextBlob taggers as well as pyStatParser. Unfortunately, none of them offer dependency grammar.

Comment: Chocolatey doesn't install anything there! Everything installed goes either into it's own folder somewhere or C:\Chocolatey\lib.